# Asp.net (SQL) Simple Login Form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, web, webforms

I'm kinda new to asp.net but I'm learning fast, tho I cant find any good web forms tutorial for login page written in vb, I'm using the offline application tutorials to learn and I just change the commands, 
So i've come to a simple error for you guys, the problem is with the dsc.sqlclient, probably there's not such command, but what should I use?
Thanks a lot anyway!

```
   Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then
            ' check for username & password in the database
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=LoginDB;Integrated Security=True")

            ' Get the row corresponding the given username and password
            Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From Users Where Username='" + txtUname.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"

            Dim dsc As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

            ' Fill the dataset 
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            dsc.sqlclient.sqlcommand(ds, "Users")

            ' if there no entry then the user is invalid
            If ds.Tables("Users").Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
            Else
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is it custom membership? Identity?

Comment: Yes custom membership but I want just a simple login form for now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like this:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then
            ' check for username & password in the database
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=LoginDB;Integrated Security=True")

            ' Get the row corresponding the given username and password
            Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From Users Where Username='" + txtUname.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"

            objConn.Open()

            ' Fill the dataset 
            Dim ds As New DataSet("Users")
            Dim daExample As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objConn)
            daExample.Fill(ds, "Users2")

            ' if there no entry then the user is invalid
            If ds.Tables("Users").Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
            Else
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
            End If
            objConn.close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

but you can also take this:

```
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
                If Page.IsValid Then
                    ' check for username & password in the database
                    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=LoginDB;Integrated Security=True")

                    ' Get the row corresponding the given username and password
                    Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From Users Where Username='" + txtUname.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"
                    'I recommend not to use * in querys
                    Dim dsc As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

                    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
                    dr = dsc.ExecuteReader()

                     If dr.HasRows = True Then
                        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
                     Else
                         Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
                     End If
                End If
       End Sub
```

Comment: I found the answer your code helped me a lot but with some minor tweaks, thanks a lot mate!!

Comment: @AlexandrosStark you're welcome !! luck!! pd: mark the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot guys, this is the correct answer tho, **kbworkshop** helped me a lot!

For anyone wanna know this is the code

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then
            ' check for username & password in the database
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=LoginDB;Integrated Security=True")

            ' Get the row corresponding the given username and password
            Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From Users Where Username='" + txtUname.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"
            'I recommend not to use * in querys
            Dim dsc As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            dr = dsc.ExecuteReader()

            If dr.HasRows = True Then
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
            Else
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
            End If
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: one tip: you can declare the Connection values in the web.config archive regars alexandros!!

Answer (score 0):

*PLEASE* don't create your SELECT statement by pasting text together.

Ugh.
Never do that.

You just allow anyone to use "SQL Injection" to log in (and worse) without a
password.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class log
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=F:\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim log As String = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND password='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"

        Session("user") = TextBox1.Text

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(log, cn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader

        cn.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            Response.Redirect("showdata.aspx")
        Else
            Response.Redirect("log.aspx")

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use SqlDataAdapter class to fill your dataset:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("My ConnectionString");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = SQL;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

conn.Open();
da.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
```

VB.Net:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("My ConnectionString")
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandText = SQL
da.SelectCommand = cmd
Dim ds As New DataSet()

conn.Open()
da.Fill(ds)
conn.Close()
```